# Singleton Service Provider not found when created object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can someone help me as to why the code bellow does not work. I created a ServicePrvoider which runs, i register the singleton, but then when i try to use it Laravel cant find it. I believe Laravel is capable of resolving classes from `use`, and it works just from using `app->make`.

Thanks.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Plivo\RestAPI;

class PlivoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
        $this->app->singleton('\App\Plivo', function ($app) {
            return new RestAPI( config('plivo.id'), config('plivo.token') );
        });

        $value = $this->app->make('\App\Plivo'); // This works
        $value = new \App\Plivo; // This throws a not found error
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to load service provider in config app.php how you are loading other service providers.

Comment: I have loaded it in my app.php config. If i stick `dd(1);`  in register it does fire. But it errors on the line `$value = new \App\Plivo;`